# Trying to find a bijection between rational and irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

I saw the proof of cantor proving set of all sequence of zeros and one is uncountable(in Rudin analysis book) and I have a doubt, if we take set of all real number between 0 and 1.1111111...and so on and let me denote all irrational numbers by small letters and rationals as capital letters. Suppose I take two irrational numbers a and b then I can find a rational number between a and b, let the rational number be A which is located between a and b, so if their is another irrational number c greater than A, then I can find another rational number greater than A and less than c.
Now the question is, haven't I found a bijective function between rationals and irrationals between 0 and 1.11111111111....

I am pretty sure their is a flaw here, please help me to find this flaw.

Comment: I have tried to edit your question, but I still feel something is not being properly asked.

Comment: Your premise is that if you extend this process in a countably infinite way, then you will have defined a function on all real numbers (well, on the interval, but that's superfluous). Unfortunately, your premise is exactly what you would need to prove.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't even defined a function at all.  Let $X$ be your set of rationals and $Y$ be your set of irrationals.  To define a bijection $f:X\to Y$, you first of all have to define a function.  That is, you have to describe a rule that given an element $x\in X$, gives you a single element $f(x)\in Y$.  You haven't done that.

Comment: I to the contradiction feel like i have proved the number of rational and irrational between 0 and 0.1111111..to be same.

Comment: @Mukil What is the image under your map for $1/2,$ and what is the image of $\sqrt{2}/2$? The description you gave does not allow one to find either of these explicitly, so it seems the map is not uniquely defined.

Answer (score 0):

So, you've sort of described a bijection, but not quite. It sounds like you're saying that to each *pair* of irrationals you can attach a rational, and vice versa; but you haven't said anything to indicate that the rational is different each time. Certainly there is a rational between $\sqrt{2}/2$ and $\sqrt{2}/2 + 0.1$; certainly there is also a rational between $\sqrt{2}/2 - 0.1$ and $\sqrt{2}/2 + 0.2$. But in both cases, $0.75$ would fit the bill.

Conversely, you're attaching an irrational to each pair of rationals, but you haven't shown you obtain every irrational that way; there's no reason to believe that there aren't many irrationals that simply aren't needed.

Comment: "you've sort of described a bijection": I disagree strongly with this statement.

Comment: The poster has described an association relating every element of one set with an element of the other, and vice versa; I'd call that a "sort of" bijection. As the rest of my response indicated, it's not actually a bijection, but it's reminiscent enough of one that the poster's confusion is understandable.

Comment: The poster has described no such thing.

Comment: The poster seems to disagree with you. In any case, do you have a substantive mathematical objection to my response?

Comment: @Reese yeah but since playing with infinity causes so much trouble,as you've said 0.75 fits but so will 0.76 and 0.74 so cant we fix this numbers to each number?

Comment: @Reese its just confusing since we can find rational between each irrational.

Comment: or can you just prove me wrong by giving a contradiction and show me that i'm wrong.

Comment: The contradiction is Cantor's diagonalization proof. You're right the 0.76 and 0.74 would also work in the scenario I've suggested, but you haven't specified how your bijection chooses which one to use. Cantor's diagonalization proves that your bijection will eventually start using the same rational over and over.